# handling password string with escape character in C#

Tags: c#, string

c# - 
    password string "[df4\'456"

I have to use this string without losing any characters. How do I do that in c#? 
When I send this string it removes the `\`.

I tried with adding additional . It goes with two \. I tried this -

```
password = password.Replace("\'", @"\'");
```

It did not work?

Comment: How did you “send this string” and what does “did not work” mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I have fixed issues in English and marked up your code.  This is done by prefixing it with 4 spaces.  Please explain what "did not work" means.

Comment: You really should be using `System.Security.SecureString` to work with passwords. Using a normal `string` object is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

string password = @"[df4\'456";

The @ makes it a verbatim string literal and basically escapes any special characters for you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a *verbatin string literal*

```
 string password = @"df4\'456";
```

Or use *escaping* (double back slash)

```
 string password = "df4\\'456";
```

See [C# String Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.
But Which will work when we print it. but when i use it login it goes with two \\.

Comment: The two \\ is just how the VS debugger shows a string with special characters.